# angularjs nullable select if null then

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, null

I have in my html angularjs select with null posibility:

```
<span class="nullable"> 
    <select ng-model="ViewLevel" ng-change="selChanged()"
            ng-options="camptype.name for camptype in campTypes">
                <option value="">-- choose campaign type --</option>
    </select>
</span>
```

and in js controller method to check if user selected something from list or nullable option

```
     $scope.selChanged = function() {
            if ($scope.ViewLevel == null) {
                $scope.getTypeData();
                console.log("nullek");
            } else {
                $scope.getCampaignData();
                console.log("nie nullek");
            }
        }
```

But it doesn't work. Always if clause is true, even if in firebug I can see that ViewLevel is not null. Why?

EDIT: screen from firebug
ViewLevel is an object with property but if clause was true:

[image: diagram]

Comment: What about `if (!$scope.ViewLevel) {`?

Comment: seems to work fine http://jsbin.com/jekuv/1/edit?console,output

Comment: @sylwester doesnt work in my project. Outputing this variable in gui works fine but if clause is still always true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rather than checking against null, using ! operator, it will check for both null/undefined

```
    $scope.selChanged = function() {
        if (!$scope.ViewLevel) {
            $scope.getTypeData();
            console.log("nullek");
        } else {
            $scope.getCampaignData();
            console.log("nie nullek");
        }
    }
```

**EDIT**

as per angularjs recommendation: your ngModel must have a dot, and that would solve the problem for you.

```
//somewhere in your controller
$scope.selected = {}
```

and then in your html

```
<select ng-model="selected.ViewLevel" ng-change="selChanged()"
        ng-options="camptype.name for camptype in campTypes">
            <option value="">-- choose campaign type --</option>
</select>
```

and then again fix if in your function. check for $scope.selected.ViewLevel

```
 $scope.selChanged = function() {
    if (!$scope.selected.ViewLevel) {
        $scope.getTypeData();
        console.log("nullek");
    } else {
        $scope.getCampaignData();
        console.log("nie nullek");
    }
   }
```

Comment: Doesn't changed anything, still if clause is always true.

Comment: Can you setup a plunker

Comment: after copying code to plunker it works... but in my project it doesnt

Comment: in that case.. something in your setup is having the problem, i suspect that `$scope.ViewLevel` is not getting updated... can you console log `$scope.ViewLevel` and check

Comment: In batarank I found that ViewLevel is in scope which is child of my scope. How to access it ?

Comment: It was packed in tabs... that was the case, thats why ViewLevel was in childs scope